# Frequency dependent spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, spring, oscillators

Consider a harmonic oscillator without damping:
$$m x''+ F_s=0,$$ where $F_s$ is the force induced by the spring (usually $F_s=kx$).

Now, consider that the spring's response for a harmonic excitation, $x(t)=A(\omega)\sin(\omega t)$ is given by: $F_s(t)=k(\omega)A(\omega)\sin(\omega t),$ for a single frequency $\omega$.

How does that dependence affects the natural frequency of the system?

In theory one can assume that any excitation can be decomposed into Fourier sin and cosine components that would result to a similarly aggregated force.

Assuming that $x(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega$, would result to $F_s(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}k(\omega)A(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega$. The trigonometrics $A(\omega)e^{i\omega t}$ will be collected under the same integral which will lead to the following characteristic equation: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[m\omega^2-k(\omega)\right]A(\omega)e^{i\omega t}d\omega=0\Rightarrow m\omega^2-k(\omega)=0\; \forall\omega,$$
which changes a lot the behavior of the problem (e.g. $\omega^3=m/k$ for $k(\omega)=k/\omega$) and may as well lead to infinite eigenvalue solutions, e.g. $k(\omega)=k\omega^2\sin(\omega)$
. Is this approach correct in any way? How can a problems of this nature be resolved? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "How does that change the natural frequency of the system?". Also, if $k$ is a constant, we can put it inside the Fourier integral and we obtain the characteristic equation. If $k$ is a function of $\omega$, I don't see how we obtain your stated characteristic equation -- I don't say it's wrong, I just don't see it. Maybe you could state a reference.

Comment: I mean, if $k=k_0$ is constant, then the natural frequency will be $\sqrt{k_0/m}$. So how can we calculate the oscillating frequency with this dependence in place? Also, regarding the Fourier, if we may say that due to superposition of the forces we need to add infinite forcing terms, one for every frequency. I'll edit the post to demonstrate that. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: If $k$ is not constant then how do you define $F_s(x) = k \,x$? Or is it $F_s(\omega,x) = k(\omega) \,x$? Note that now $x(t)$ isn;t sufficient, but you need $x(\omega,t)$.

Comment: This differential equation $~ \begin{aligned}\ddot x+\dfrac{k}{m}x=0\Rightarrow \,
k=\omega ^{2}m\end{aligned}~$ has also your solution ?

Comment: Ok, I might have messed up the notation a bit. Yes, it is $F_s(\omega,x(\omega,t))=k(\omega)x(\omega,t)$. The idea is that if we see the spring as a black box that we harmonically deform and we measure a harmonic reaction force. However, the stiffness $k=F_s/x$ that we measure  is different for every frequency $\omega$ that we test. Then we attach a mass and we leave the system to oscillate without external forcing. What is the resulting frequency of the free oscillation?